# If compact and sequentially compact sets coincide then the space is sequential

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying to prove or disprove the following but I've made no advances:

> Let X be a topological space. Then $X$ is a sequential space if and only if for any subset $A$ of $X$ the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is compact.
> 2. $A$ is sequentially compact.

Is any of the implications true? How can we prove or disprove any of them?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Do you mean "$X$ is a sequential space if and only if for any subset $A\subseteq X$, the following are equivalent: (a) $A$ is compact. (b) $A$ is sequentially compact."? Without the sequential assumption, neither implies the other: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=~compact%2BSequentially%20Compact https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=compact%2B~Sequentially%20Compact

Comment: I'm suspicious. What if $X$ has very few or no nontrivial compact sets?

Comment: @StevenClontz Yes, I'll change it to make it more understandable.

Comment: I don't have a full answer but here's some hints: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Sequential%2BSequentially%20Compact%2B~Compact shows sequential doesn't make both 1+2 equivalent. Every sequential and [countably] compact space is sequentially compact, but I'm not sure that extends to subspaces without some extra separation axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is called *anti-compact*, if every compact subset is finite.

Of course, finite spaces are also sequentially compact. Vice versa, if a space is anti-compact, then also sequentially compact subsets are finite.
Hence, each anti-compact space fulfills the right-hand-side condition.

Thus,to show that "$\Leftarrow$" does not hold, we just need to construct an anti-compact, non sequential space. Here is an example:

Let $x$ be a point of $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$.
$ X := \mathbb N \cup \{x\}$ as a subspace of $\beta \mathbb N$.

Assume $C$ is a compact subspace of $X$. Then it is closed in $\beta \mathbb N$. However, as it is well-known, infinite, closed subsets of $\beta \mathbb N$ have cardinality $2^c$. Hence $C$ is finite and thus $X$ is anti-compact.
Moreover, since $\beta \mathbb N$ has no non-trivial sequences, the same holds for $X$. Since $X$ is not discrete, it is not sequential.

Note that $X$ is completely regular, T2.

For "$\Rightarrow$" note that $\omega_1$ with the order topology is first countable, hence sequential. It is sequentially compact, but not compact.
Hence, "$\Rightarrow$" is also false in general, if really equivalence in the right-hand condition is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One implication is down (the one that I suspected was not true because I didn't find any information), but what about the other one?

Comment: @Eparoh: I assumed the other direction would be pretty much clear.  Anyway, I added a note for this one to my answer.